# What's the risk of modifying the state without setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that modifying directly the state without `setState(...)` won't update the UI automatically, but I can still do this:

```
this.state.myValue = "foo";
this.forceUpdate();
```

I am also aware that React waits for certain moments to update several components in a single pass, but are there really any compelling reason why I shouldn't alter directly the state without `setState(...)`?

There are 2 scenarios where altering directly the state would be beneficial for me:

- If I have to modify an element of a very long array, the performance gain from the 'cluster update' of `setState(...)` would be negligible compared to the performance gain from not shallow copying the entire array every time.
- If I have 2 references to the same object in 2 different properties of the state and I want to modify this object, I would prefer to do this modification on a single property, but if I use `setState(...)` I would copy the object and lose the reference.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: because it leads to odd bugs [why not modify react state directly](https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/)

Comment: And your changes might be overwritten by pending state changes that have not yet been applied to the state

Answer (score 1):

If you modify state directly and at same time some other logic also updates state. It is not guaranteed that you have correct state or other logic is having correct state.

It might give you unpredictable results and behavior. So it is always advisable to use only setState() as this is async and update state immutably.

Answer (score 0):

The risks of modifying the state with out `setState()` are:

- Changing the state directly will not let you have the `render()` method called and other life cycle methods.
- `setState()` changes the `DOM` otherwise nothing will be changed
- **The docs says:** state is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied. It should not be directly mutated. Instead, changes should be represented by building a new object based on the input from state and props